# How to delete VPN connection (.pbk) in DotRas C#?

Tags: c#, vpn, dotras

When my VPN client connects to my VPN server, it creates a .PBK connection, but when i trying to create another connection with another IP, it throws me

```
System.ArgumentException: 'ConnectionName' already exists in the phone book.
```

I know i can create different connection name each time i trying to connect, but over time there will be too much unnecessary connections, how can i remove my connection via DotRas or manually?

This folder is totally clear. Don't know what to do.

```
%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to my question. If you declare your entry like this:

```
RasEntry entry = RasEntry.CreateVpnEntry(EntryName, ip, RasVpnStrategy.Default,
RasDevice.GetDeviceByName("(PPTP)", RasDeviceType.Vpn));
```

You need to use `Remove()` method:

```
this.AllUsersPhoneBook.Entries.Remove(Entry);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `RasCollection`, which is what `RasPhoneBook.Entries` is, provides several methods that can be used. In the end, it is an `ICollection`/`IEnumerable`.

```
...
public abstract class RasCollection<TObject> : MarshalByRefObject, ICollection<TObject>, IEnumerable<TObject>, IEnumerable where TObject : class
{
    ...

    public int Count { get; }
    ...

    public void Add(TObject item);
    public void Clear();
    public bool Contains(TObject item);
    ...
    ...
    public int IndexOf(TObject item);
    public bool Remove(TObject item);
    public void RemoveAt(int index);
    ...
}
```

To remove items, one can use `Remove()` given a `RasEntry`, `RemoveAt()` given an index, or `Clear()` to remove everything.

Additionally, `RasEntryCollection` provides `public bool Remove(string name)` which one can use to remove an entry given its name.

<sub>Source: I needed to create a VPN software recently. Lack of documentation did not help.</sub>